# Did $ use to sometimes match a newline in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I seem to remember that there were certain conditions under which `$` would match a newline (not "just before"), but I can't find anything in the docs that would confirm that.  Did that use to be true in an earlier version of Perl or am I dreaming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing two very similar things. The `$` matches *at* the end of a string if `/m` is not used, and *at* the end of a string or at the end of a string except for a final newline if `/m` is used. However, it does not actually *match* (consume) the newline itself. You could still match the newline character itself with something else in the regexp, for instance `\n`; or, if you also use `/s`, then `/blah$./sm` would theoretically match "blah\n" even though the `$` is not the last thing in the regex.

(The reason this doesn't actually work is that both `$.` and `$\` are actually interpreted as special variables instead of as `$` plus `.`, so it is actually quite hard to put something after a `$` in a regexp. Confusing, isn't it?)

Comment: I guess you could use $ . if you had /x

Comment: Not quite right. "at the end of a string or before a newline at the end of a string" if no /m, "at the end of a string or before any newline" if /m.  Just "the end of the string" is \z.

Comment: To use $ anywhere in a regex, without /m you can just say \Z (not \z).  With /m, you can stick `$` in a `$dollar` variable and interpolate that (as `${dollar}` if needed).  Or do e.g. `/@{['$']}./`

Answer (score 5):

That has always been the case. See [perldoc perlreref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html#ANCHORS) (`$` is an anchor):

> `$`  Match string end (or line, if `/m` is used) or before newline

You should use `\z` if you want to match the end of the string:

> `\z` Match absolute string end

Comment: Yes. `"123\n" =~ /^\d+$/` is true. Which means all sorts of potential fun for your validation code if you get it wrong. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you pass the `/s` modifier to a regexp, then `$` matches the end of the string and allows `.` to match `\n`.

This can be a bit confusing. For a string of `foo\n`, observe the difference between:

`/.$/ # matches 'o'`

`/.$/s # still matches 'o'`

`/.+$/s # matches 'foo\n'`

`/.\z/ # doesn't match at all`

`/.\z/s # matches '\n'`

Comment: Sorry... not relevant to my question

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, you don't mean what you think you mean. `$` doesn't do any character matching, it does positional matching, so the question you might be asking is whether `$` matches before or after the newline.

Comment: I remember something about it consuming the newline itself

Comment: @JoelFan => `$` is a zero width positional assertion, it never consumes any characters

Comment: It's `/m` that changes the meaning of the anchors (`^` and `$`); `/s` only changes the meaning of the dot.  `$` *always* matches at the end of the string or before a newline at the end of the string.  In `/m` mode it also matches before any *other* newline.  At least, that's how it works in Perl; there could be Perl-derived flavors that don't work exactly like Perl in that regard, but I can't think of any offhand.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the 'm' modifier, '$' will match (but not consume) end of *line* characters.  Normally '$' matches end of *string*.

```
my $sample = "first\nsecond\nthird";
$sample =~ s/$/END/mg;
print $sample;
```

Produces:

```
firstEND
secondEND
thirdEND
```

If you want to *consume* the newline, just use the \n escape character:

```
my $sample = "first\nsecond\nthird";
$sample =~ s/\n/END/g;
print $sample;
```

Now you get:

```
firstENDsecondENDthird
```

Note that the 'm' modifier also affects '^' in the same way as '$'.